# Combining two columns in SQL wwithout a key and no duplicate within columns

Tags: sql, join, toad

Is there anyway we I can combine two columns independently (match on "index") and have `NULLS` where there is no match. Let's look at following example

```
col1
-----
A
B
C
D
```

and

```
Col2
----
1
2
```

Desired output

```
 Col1    Col2
 ------------
 A       1
 B       2
 C       
 D
```

I have tried different variation of `left join`, `inner join`, `outer join`, `cross join`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`.  One method:

```
select t1.col1, t2.col2
from (select t1.*, row_number() over (order by col1) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1 full join
     (select t2.*, row_number() over (order by col2) as seqnum
      from table1 t2
     ) t2
     on t2.seqnum = t1.seqnum;
```

Note:  This works regardless of which table has more rows.